# Css animation not working in safari (no problems in Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: css, safari, google-fonts

I have the following animation in css:

It works perfectly in chrome and firefox. In Safari (desktop and mobile) the font-family doesn't change. I have tried using a different font with no success.

```css
.logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5em;
  animation: animate 1.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%,
  100% {
    text-shadow: -4.5px -4.5px 0 #0ff, 4.5px 4.5px 0 #f00;
  }
  25% {
    font-family: "Courier New", serif; */
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #55acee;
    text-shadow: 4.5px 4.5px 0 #0ff, -4.5px -4.5px 0 #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="logo">Logo</p>
```

Comment: You declare the `logo` font-family as `sans-serif` (Safe Font - what font exactly? depends on the browser). Read more her: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp. and her: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/what-is-the-default-serif-sans-serif-and-monospace-font-family-for-mac-os-x. If you want specific google font, for example, Roboto see this demo (+ read google fonts "Get Started " docs): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?font=Roboto

Comment: The animation works perfectly on chrome and firefox-  The google font is loading correctly on these browsers. Safari is the problem- I have tried it with other font-familys on Safari with no success. The problem isn't with the sans-serif font rather the "Courier New", serif;